# AngularJS: How to set controller's property from a directive when using the "Controller As" syntax?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/olukaf/1/edit)

Consider the following example that uses the [Controller As syntax](http://www.egghead.io/video/tTihyXaz4Bo):

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as my">
  <div>
    {{ my.message }}
  </div>
  <button my-directive>
    Click me 
  </button>
</body>
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function() {
  this.message = 'Hello';
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        // Change 'message' here
      });
    }
  };
});
```

How could I set controller's `message` from the directive?

Without the "Controller As" syntax, I simply do: [**(DEMO)**](http://jsbin.com/ehogod/1/edit)

```js
scope.message = 'World';
scope.$apply();
```

But, how would you do this when using the "Controller As" syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the controller is defined *as* **my** you need to use:

```
scope.my.message = 'World';
scope.$apply();
```